# How can I control a progress element using JavaScript for Loading visualization?

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I need help with adding a loader to my HTML document. Here's the page without the loader:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Webpage</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <script>
      /*
      
      Script goes here for the loader.
      I think I might have an idea, I could use the "load" event.
      
      */
    </script>
    <style>
      
      h1 {
        color: green;
        font: 24px Courier;
      }
      
      .css-format-class {
        color: red;
        font: 16px Arial;
      }
      
    </style>
    <center>
      <h1>My Simple Webpage</h1>
    </center>
    <br>
    <p class="css-format-class">I wish I could add a loader GIF onto this page...</p>
    <!--I need a loader somewhere in this webpage...-->
    <!--If you know the solution, please feel free to comment.-->
  </body>
</html>
```

I found this bit of code in HTML5, but don't know how to make JavaScript manipulate this tag:

```html
<progress id="loader" value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

If you know how, let me know.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to load, and how? Through AJAX?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "loader".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Note that asking for libraries is off-topic, and you haven't shown anything indicating any research into this subject.

Comment: I mean using the <select> tag in HTML for the loader. It would be easiest that way instead of a GIF in the middle of the page appearing and disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the [progress element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) (e.g. using [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) and then update the *value* property, which maps to the attribute of the same name. See the snippet below for a demonstration, where [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is used to call a function every second to update the value.

The code below waits until the DOM is ready by adding an event listener (using [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) to add a callback when the event [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) happens. That way it doesn't try to access elements in the DOM (e.g. the progress element) before it is ready.

```js
var progress, date, interval;
// wait until DOM has been loaded to perform DOM Manipulations
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  date = Date.now(); //current timestamp since UNIX epoch

  //get a reference to the progress element using its id attribute
  progress = document.getElementById('loader');
  interval = setInterval(updateProgress, 1000);
});
function updateProgress() {
    msg.innerHTML = 'begin updateProgress() - progress.value = '+progress.value + "<br>" + msg.innerHTML;
    if (progress.value >= 100) {
      //stop running this function after value reaches 100 (percent)
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    var newDate = Date.now();
    var milliseconds = newDate - date;

    var seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
    loader.value += seconds;
  }
```

```html
<progress id="loader" value="15" max="100"></progress>
<div id="msg" style="max-height:100px;overflow-y: auto"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, I think that helped, I still need to try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I thought about using document.getElementById(), but didn't know how to call the method after that to get the value to change on the progress.

Comment: Here's the link to where I'm testing that code, but somehow it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: I'm thinking it's just that it's an online editor. It might affect it or run a little different, but I need an offline editor or a .html file to run it.

Comment: Well I thought that too but then noticed that it defaults to the _index.js_ file, which is blank but _index.html_ is not blank... Try looking at that tab or else [use this updated repl.it example](https://repl.it/F3Kh/3) where the javascript code has been moved to _index.js_

Comment: awesome, it works, thanks! i just need to add it to the webpage like i posted above.